# iOS Facebook SDK showing $(PRODUCT_NAME) in Login Screen

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdkloginkit

Just updated to the latest Facebook Login SDK 4.27.1 using it on iOS11. Now the login screen (see screen shot) shows what I assume is a placeholder: $(PRODUCT_NAME). This worked flawless with the previous FBLoginSDK (4.18)

Here is the call to the FBSDK:

```
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
//todo: define facebook permissions
facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: view, handler: {
```

Screen Shot Facebook login screen

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us the content of your plist

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.

Using FBSDK 4.30

In my case it was a localized info.plist. I added a few languges and let the files create by XCode (dowsnt really work well in XCode, but hey it worked...)

There was a line in every .plist for each language saying

```
/* (No Comment) */
"CFBundleName" = "$(PRODUCT_NAME)";
```

I thought thats ok, but XCode does not replace this String with the content of that variable, it uses this exact string instead.

So change this value in every language-file and it will work again.